# How i can implement Compound Component pattern in React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
// 1) ModalContext

const ModalContext = createContext();

// 2) Parent Component
const Modal = ({ children }) => {
  const [openName, setOpenName] = useState("");

  const close = () => setOpenName("");
  const open = setOpenName;
  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{ openName, close, open }}>
      {children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
};

// 3) Child Components
const Open = ({ children, opens: opensWindowName }) => {
  const { open } = useContext(ModalContext);
  return cloneElement(children, { onClick: () => open(opensWindowName) });
};

const Window = ({ children, name }) => {
  const { openName, close } = useContext(ModalContext);
  const ref = useOutsideClick(close);

  if (name !== openName) return null;
  return createPortal(
    <Overlay>
      <StyledModal ref={ref}>
        <Button onClick={close}>
          <HiXMark />
        </Button>
        {cloneElement(children, { closeModal: close })}
      </StyledModal>
    </Overlay>,
    document.body
  );
};

// 4) Setting Properties to parent
Modal.Open = Open;
Modal.Window = Window;

export default Modal;
```

In my above code block, i'm using React + JavaScript and everything working fine. But as i tried to implement it via TypeScript, i faced difficulty in usage of 'CloneElement' and the most important thing step no. 4 where we define childs as properties to the parent. below are the two steps that make me difficult to implement this feature

```
{cloneElement(children, { closeModal: close })}
```

and the step no 4

```
Modal.Open = Open;
Modal.Window = Window;
```

please resolve my issue and guide me how i can implement this. even with an efficient approach